# Left-Joining multiple (40) files into a single table

Tags: database, postgresql

As a total newcomer to database management, i am currently Running Postgresql 9.3 through PgAdmin. My goal is to condense 40 files into one table, where my setup is as follows:

A table that contains a standalone `Master Key` Column with ~400k unique integer observations.

```
|Master Key|
```

20 files, three columns each. First column contains an integer key that is guaranteed to match an observation on the "master" column. Second and third columns contain integer values.

```
|Master Key-like Value| IntValue1 | IntValue 2|
```

20 files with multiple columns containing text details, where first column contains an integer key in the same fashion.

```
|Master Key-Like Value| Multiple Data |
```

I am currently thinking about importing all of the files into a corresponding table each and left joining them, where the final output would be:

```
Master Key | File 1 IntValue 1 | File 1 Intvalue 2| File 2 Intvalue 1 ... | File 20 Intvalue 2 | Multiple Data |
```

Placing null values if no corresponding value is found. (This is a very possible scenario, where the int values are organized in an implicit date-like fashion for every file in the sequence)

Will a left join get me such output? Is there a more efficient way to concatenate such table?

Answer (score 0):

Importing each file in a separate table and doing a big join is a good approach.

Database engines are optimized for just this kind of computation.
You could achieve something similar with the unix [join command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/join.1.html), but it can only process two files at a time and would likely take more time.